# Adding button column in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a datagridview which displays sale detail from database. I want to add a delete button at the end of the columns so i can see the delete button at the end of every row. I know to add a button column to datagridview. but here iam displaying data from database and when it displays data i want a custom button column at the end of the gridview. how can we achieve this? I added a button column but it comes at the first position of the datagridview.. after that only my whole data displays. I want it at last position. Can someone help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `DisplayIndex` property of `DataGridView.Columns[columnName]` to (columns count - 1) to display button column in the end.

```
dataGridView1.Columns["ButtonColumn"].DisplayIndex = dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn(v=vs.100).aspx) and add it manually to your DataGridView.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn dgvButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
myDataGridView.Columns.Add(dgvButton);
```

And for accessing an Event with Row Data:

```
myDataGridView.CellContentClick += myDataGridView_CellContentClick;
```

Calling method:

```
private void myDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        //TODO - Your Row Delete Code ;D
    }
}
```

Comment: OP asked how to change column order i guess.. _i want a custom button column at the end of the gridview. how can we achieve this?_

Comment: @abdul `myDataGridView.Columns.Add()` puts the column normally to end. But there are more misunderstandings. Let's whats OP will edit.

Comment: yes.. i thought of shifting an existing column, lets see :)